# How does Domino Administrator read files information?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I need to read few properties from each database (f.x. "Is Logged" and "Templates") located on a specific server. The challenge though - it has to be done quickly (without Database.Open() - otherwise it takes to much time).

I tried to solve the task with Catalog.nsf, just loop all documents and read information from them, that would be OK, however it seems it does not store "Is Logged" flag.

I have also tried DbDirectory and it allow to get some info about database but database.getOption(Database.DBOPT_NOTRANSACTIONLOGGING) throw an error that database needs to be opened.

I wonder how Domino Administrator does that? It loads data very quickly and if I change database - updates do not appear instantly so it must use some kind of cache.

I am curious if that is true and if it is possible to re-use somehow their approach.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don‘t need to open databases to get some information. Just create a NotesDbDirectory and loop through it... if you do not call db.Open("","") it should be sufficiently fast and still give you that information using the db.GetOption(DBOPT_NOTRANSACTIONLOGGING) method.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately db.GetOption requires to open database.
I will update my question about that as well.